# What rune words can I build at lower levels?

Tags: diablo-ii

I started a new ladder character and am beginning to find random runes in Act II (Normal).  What rune words can I reasonably find runes for and create while I'm still in Normal?

I know of Stealth (TalEth), but the words on the Arreat Summit aren't listed by level, rather alphabetically.  Is there a handy reference that lists them all by max rune level?

Comment: One of the best low/mid level runes imo is Stealth for your merc armor (ShaelUmPulLum) and Spirit(TalThulOrtAmn) for your own shield/weapon (if you are a caster).  Duress(ShaelUmThul) is another good choice for merc armor that's fairly easy to get.  Make sure you put it into an ethereal armor as merc armor does not degrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DiabloWiki has a list [here](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Runewords#List_of_All_Runewords_by_Rank) of the runewords in order of rank.

[image: Runewords by Rank]

Comment: Can you... do something about the table?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of runewords ordered by the level required

- Nadir (13)
- Steel (13)
- Malice (15)
- Stealth (17)
- Leaf (19)
- Ancient's Pledge (21)
- Zephyr (21)
- Holy Thunder (23)
- Myth (25)
- Spirit (25)
- King's Grace (25)
- Edge (25)
- Strength (25)
- Honor (27)
- Lore (27)
- Insight (27)
- Radiance (27)
- Peace (29)
- Rhyme (29)
- White (35)
- Black (35)
- Memory (37)
- Splendor (37)
- Smoke (37)
- Melody (39)
- Harmony (39)
- Obedience (41)
- Lionheart (41)
- Lawbringer (43)
- Wealth (43)
- Voice of Reason (43)
- Passion (43)
- Treachery (43)
- Enlightenment (45)
- Bone (47)
- Gloom (47)
- Stone (47)
- Duress (47)
- Crescent Moon (47)
- Sanctuary (49)
- Venom (49)
- Rain (49)
- Prudence (49)
- Delirium (51)
- Kingslayer (53)
- Rift (53)
- Death (55)
- Silence (55)
- Heart of the Oak (55)
- Principle (55)
- Exile (57)
- Call to Arms (57)
- Chaos (57)
- Grief (59)
- Fortitude (59)
- Oath (59)
- Dragon (61)
- Bramble (61)
- Wind (61)
- Eternity (63)
- Infinity (63)
- Chains of Honor (63)
- Beast (63)
- Wrath (63)
- Last Wish (65)
- Destruction (65)
- Enigma (65)
- Phoenix (65)
- Brand (65)
- Faith (65)
- Famine (65)
- Fury (65)
- Dream (65)
- Ice (65)
- Pride (67)
- Hand of Justice (67)
- Doom (67)
- Breath of the Dying (69)

For a more detailed view, you can check the [Runewords article on the diablo 2 wiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Runewords).